# System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotAvailableException при наведении на элемент в меню notepad.exe

Tags: c#, windows, исключения, uiautomation

Пытаюсь сделать логгирование наведения курсора на пункты меню в блокноте через библиотеку Windows.Automation. Однако, при наведении выбрасывается ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал добавлять хендлер к automationElement.GetUpdatedCache(CacheRequest.Current), результат точно такой же:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
            Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Exception.ToString());
    };

    Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
            AutomationElement.FromHandle(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").First().MainWindowHandle), 
            TreeScope.Element, OnNotepadControlAction);
}
```

Код метода OnNotepadControlAction в контексте проблемы влияния не оказывает, но на всякий случай привожу и его:

```
private void OnNotepadControlAction(object sender, AutomationEventArgs automationEventArgs)
{
    var spacing = "   ";
    var rootElement = sender as AutomationElement;
        
    Console.WriteLine(rootElement.Current.ClassName);
        
    Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(SelectionItemPattern.ElementSelectedEvent,
               rootElement.GetUpdatedCache(CacheRequest.Current), TreeScope.Children,
               new AutomationEventHandler(OnUIAutomationEvent));
        
    var children = rootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
        
    foreach (AutomationElement child in children)
    {
        var childrenSpacing = spacing + "   ";
        
        Console.WriteLine(childrenSpacing + child.Current.ClassName);
        
        var ch = child.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, System.Windows.Automation.Condition.TrueCondition);
        
        foreach (AutomationElement c in ch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(childrenSpacing + c.Current.Name);
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(TextPattern.TextChangedEvent, c.GetUpdatedCache(CacheRequest.Current), TreeScope.Descendants,
                new AutomationEventHandler(OnUIAutomationEvent));
        }  
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи и совету.

UPD. Шаги к воспроизведению:

1. Запустить блокнот
2. Запустить программу
3. Нажать на любой из пунктов меню (файл, правка, ...)

Также стек:

```
>   JetstyleTest.exe!JetstyleTest.MainWindow..ctor.AnonymousMethod__1_0(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs eventArgs) Строка 38  C#
[Переход от машинного кода к управляемому]  
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.Misc.ThrowWin32ExceptionsIfError(int errorCode)   Нет данных
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.ProxyManager.GetClassName(MS.Win32.NativeMethods.HWND hwnd)   Нет данных
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.ProxyManager.ProxyProviderFromHwnd(MS.Win32.NativeMethods.HWND hwnd, int idChild, int idObject)   Нет данных
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.OnGetProvider(System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.ProviderType providerType) Нет данных
[Переход от машинного кода к управляемому]  
[Переход от управляемого кода к машинному]  
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.UiaNodeFromHandle(System.IntPtr hwnd)  Нет данных
UIAutomationClient.dll!System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle(System.IntPtr hwnd)   Нет данных
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.WindowHideOrCloseTracker.WinEventProc(int eventId, System.IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint eventTime) Нет данных
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.WinEventWrap.PreWinEventProc(int eventId, System.IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint eventTime)  Нет данных
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.WinEventWrap.WinEventReentrancyFilter(int winEventHook, int eventId, System.IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, int eventThread, uint eventTime)  Нет данных
[Переход от машинного кода к управляемому]  
[Переход от управляемого кода к машинному]  
UIAutomationClient.dll!MS.Internal.Automation.QueueProcessor.WaitForWork()  Нет данных
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Нет данных
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Нет данных
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Нет данных
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Нет данных
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Нет данных
```

Comment: Почему бы не приложить ошибку текстом, а таже трассировку стека, точное место возниктовения исключения, описать что именно вы делаете и как воаспроизвести ошибку, указать на ваши собственые исследования вопроса и результаты, что вы получили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришел к решению, может быть кому-то полезно будет (P.S. исключение всё равно выбрасывается).

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Exception.ToString());
    };

    var notepadWindow = AutomationElement.FromHandle(Process.GetProcessesByName(appName).First().Handle);     

    Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler((o, e) => {
        var element = o as AutomationElement;
            
        if (element != null)
           Console.WriteLine("name is {0}", element.Current.Name);                  
    });
}
```

[image]

Вывод:

[image]